# Function Returns NaN

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the distance between two points.

This is my distance function.

```
var distance = function(first, second) {
        var midValue = first - second;
        midValue *= midValue;
        return Math.sqrt(midValue);
    }
```

This is where I call the distance function.

```
xDist += distance(locations[i].x, students[j][0]);
```

When I look at the xDist's value i get NaN. I have implicitly looked the values of locations and students they are all numbers. Also, in the distance function I have looked the value of **Math.sqrt(midValue)** before I return it and it is a number.

Comment: Do you initialize `xDist` to `0` before trying to add the distance to it?

Comment: No, don't use `parseInt()` unless you have a good reason to do so.

Comment: Wait, you're squaring midValue, then square rooting it? Why?

Comment: `var midValue = Number(first) - Number(second);`

Comment: @vinayakj the `-` operator will convert strings to numbers. If the strings are not valid numbers, then it'll result in `NaN`, but then so will `parseInt()`. Also, the values may not be integers.

Comment: Try this in your browser console: `"12" - "4"`

Comment: @user3189142  To make sure I don't get a negative value.

Comment: @vinayakj you didn't try it, did you?

Comment: @Barte use Math.abs to remove negative instead

Comment: @Barte There's a `Math.abs()` function that's far less expensive. In any case, it's very hard if not impossible to guess what the problem is with this information. You'll have to show an example that demonstrates the problem, that is, at least the values of `xDist`, `locations[i].x` and `students[j][0]`.

Comment: @vinayakj then what would `parseInt()` do?

Comment: alright.. you are right.. understood

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `locations[i].x` or/and `students[j][0]` is/are `undefined` because arithmetic operations on `undefined` or, maybe they are not numbers in the first place, and thus always output `NaN`

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a initial value of xDist=0 else it would be undefined.
undefined+10= NaN

you can try this

```
var distance = function(first, second) {
        var midValue = first - second;
        midValue *= midValue;
        return Math.sqrt(midValue);
    }

var xDist=0;
xDist += distance(locations[i].x, students[j][0]);
alert(xDist);
```

Comment: xDist is defined before. Sorry I've forgot to add that part.

Answer (score -1):

Though it seems number it might not be number always. So better do a parseInt.

```
var distance = function(first, second) {
        var midValue = parseInt(first) - parseInt(second);
        midValue *= midValue;
        return Math.sqrt(midValue);
    }
```

Comment: There's really no evidence that the problem involves non-numeric values. Even if it did, the `-` and `*=` operators will perform the conversion anyway. We also don't know whether the OP really wants to be working with integers.